# Getting "error: cannot find symbol method openFileOutput(String,int)" in my Android app

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to save the results of a JSON fetch to a local file. When I try to use openFileOutput, I get `error: cannot find symbol method openFileOutput(String,int)`. Searching said that it needs Context, but I have tried every other class I have and it either keeps the same error, or I get `Non-static method 'openFileOutput(java.lang.String,Int)' cannot be referenced from a static context.`

All of my classes extend AppCompatActivity or ArrayAdapter, except the class I'm using this code in, which extends AsyncTask.

```
//SAVE JSON TO FILE
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("BonusData.xml", 0));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do file I/O in an `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: Optinally you can add extra parameter for context e.g.`writeToFile(Context con, String data)` and do `con.openFileOutput...`.

Comment: @MikeM.I realized I was mistaken in my first post. I've since edited my original question to reflect that this method is in a class extending AsyncTask. This is the JSON downloader portion of my app.

Comment: @Enzokie When I do it that way, it underlines the entire first line of that try statement and says `Method call expected`

Comment: @DJFriar if you don't mind can you post a screenshot of that `Method call expected` error here in the comment section? You can upload the image in [Imgur](https://imgur.com/) and post the link here.

Comment: @Enzokie [I posted it](https://imgur.com/a/OwEK7as)

Comment: add `new` keyword e.g. `outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter...`

Comment: @Enzokie That fixed that part, but its complaining that when I call this method I'm not passing it the Context and nothing I've tried has made it happy. I'm tried `Context`, `con`, `getContext()`, and `getApplicationContext()` and none worked. (the method call is in the screenshot, a few lines up from the one needing the keyword `new`.)

Answer (score 0):

The method `openFileOutput` belongs to the class `Context`, so you cannot use it directly from inside the `ArrayAdapter` class.

You have multiple options:

1. Either pass reference of `Context` as an argument in your method `writeToFile` and use `context.openFileOutput(...)`
2. Or use the method `getContext()` of the class `ArrayAdapter` and use `getContext().openFileOutput(...)`
3. If your `ArrayAdapter` is an inner class of your activity, don't make it (the classs) static and then you can access all methods including `openFileOutput()` directly from inside the `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: My apologies, my original version of the question had an error. I am extending AsyncTask, not ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Well in that case, you can still pass in a `Context` object via the constructor of your AsyncTask and store the application context using `context.getApplicationContext()` and use that application context to open file output. You may need to look for memory leaks in the future. But first make things work.

Comment: I did option 1 of your answer, but I used `   public jsonDownloader(Context c, String jsonURL, ListView lv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.jsonURL = jsonURL;
        this.lv = lv;
    }` to make the context work, and then just passed the context over via the writeToFile method call.